# Passing Array Values to Mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-connect

I am reading the values from a text file that hold the connect parameters to connect to Mysql Server.

The content of the file is:
localhost
user
password
databaseName

I read the file and put the file and out the values into an array.

I then try to connect to the database using the following:

```
 $connParams = $this->databaseConfigArray;
 $connection = mysqli_connect($connParams[0], $connParams[1], $connParams[2], $connParams[3]);
```

This connection always fails.  I debug and see that the strings in the array are correct and I can hard code the values and everything works fine.

Can someone tell me why the Array values don't work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the parameters in the right order?

Comment: So what does the error reporting of the mysqli extension say? At least take a look into the error log file of the http server instead of _guessing_ what might be the problem. That is what log files are there for: to tell you what the problem is!

Comment: The error that is displayed is: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.   Even when I change to 127.0.0.1 I still get the same error.  I am running PHP 5.5 on a Windows 7 machine using IIS 7

Comment: Provide `var_dump($connParams)`